# Azure application resolves to a completely different IP address than range listed in Outbound IP addresses

Tags: c#, azure, networking, azure-web-app-service

I have a web application that is hosted in Azure, I have collected the Outbound IP addresses of this application and whitelisted them in a server where this Azure application will be used.

In a public network, when I run the ping/tracert command, my Azure application resolves to one of the IP addresses in the Outbound IP address section of my Azure portal.

But when I connect to a network that my customer has given me(this network also has access to internet), and I run ping/tracert, the Azure application resolves to 146.112.61.110. This IP looks completely random, anyhow have any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

If there is a proxy in your customer's network or you're in a content delivery network like [Azure CDN](http://delivery%20network), you send requests to the web application via a reverse proxy or CDN endpoint, then your request might be responded with an IP address from that proxy or CDN edge server.

Generally, if you want to whitelist the web application in the Azure app service in your network, you could whitelist all [possible outbound IP addresses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-inbound-outbound-ips#when-outbound-ips-change) your app can use. You could refer to [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2017/02/01/how-do-i-determine-the-outbound-ip-addresses-of-my-azure-app-service/) for more details.